# What is the meant by "A high standard of illustration (both line and photo) is an editorial"?

Tags: thesis, journals

> A high standard of illustration (both line and photo) is an editorial
>   priority.

What is meant by "line" here? I am not getting this into my mind. The sentence above is taken from the "Instructions to author" part of a journal.

Comment: It probably refers to line drawing.

Comment: So, why it is written as a whole that is "line and photo" ??

Comment: It's not written as a whole: it tells you that _both_ type of illustrations, line drawings and photographs, should be of high quality.

Comment: It says "both line and photo" so 1. line and 2. photo (image). Yes, it would be clearer if they said "line or photo".

Comment: They probably mean "both vector and raster", but use non-technical language.

Answer (score 4):

"line" means "line art", and could be anything from pen drawings to graphs (plots) or other illustrations drawn with a thin pen or its electronic equivalent.

The reason line art is often listed separately from photos is that it requires a higher resolution image and usually also a different file format for high quality output.

Comment: I believe the distinction is also partly a hold-over from earlier (print) publication processes, where photographic illustrations and line art had to be handled differently by the printers when they were preparing things for the printing press. With modern digital publishing techniques, the distinction between the two types of illustrations is less critical, but the terminology sticks around.

Answer (score 1):

Though it depends on fields of the journal, it could mean the following:

- A line is a plot of the results in terms of a curve, a bar plot, some statistical demonstrations in such a curve (a 2D picture).
- A photo might mean the physical problem demonstration, for example, a set of steps, a set of environmental parameters available in the problem.

E.g. variation of our function *f* with the parameter *x*. (Line)
The following figure shows the growth of bacteria under several conditions of the parameter *x*. (Photo)